# Current IP address of phone, whether connected via WiFi or 3G

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ip-address

I need to create a function that returns the current IP address of the phone.

I found this (but it is only for when the phone is conntected to the WiFi -- I need the address even if it is connected via 3G)
http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309927273/programmatically-retrieving-ip-address-of-iphone

Further, once I have the IP address, I'd like to find the country that it's from.

Answer (score 2):

You need `pdp_ip0` instead of `en0`.

Comment: will pdp_ip0 include both wirless and 3G or only 3G ?

Comment: Only 3G. You need to get them separately. But you can reuse the code, just add parameter and call the method twice once with `en0` and once with `pdp_ip0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for one of the other adapters, "en0" is the wifi card, try "en1"

Answer (score 1):

Mapping IP address -> country isn't going to work.   Specifically, if the phone is connected to *any* consumer WiFi base station, it is almost guaranteed that said base station is using NAT (network address translation) to share a single IP amongst connected devices.  I.e. you'll see IP addresses that start with `10.0.##.##` or `192.168.1.##`.

You have to contact an external server to figure out what IP address your device is potentially hiding behind.

[Lots of info here](http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/) (though I know nothing about the company running this).